# How to read the linux timestamp in the output screen?

Tags: linux, time

I guess my linux (Ubuntu) box is crash. It printed out:

```
[422473.440904] Call Trace:
[422473.440937]   [<fffffffff81073655>] ? wq_worker_sleeping
[422473.449036]   ...
....
[422473.609529] CR2: ffffffff8
```

My question is: is [422473.609529] the time when the crash happened? What time is that? It is not the Epoch Unix time (currently 1384301380). If it is "second", then that is 117 hours, not actually mean anything.

--add picture
[image: screen shot]

Comment: time from boot, in seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Means:

```
422473.440904
   |      +----------- micro sec portion
   +------------------ seconds since boot
```

The timing information is called `printk() times`. Check [this](http://elinux.org/Printk_Times) or [this](http://elinux.org/Kernel_Debugging_Tips#Adding_timing_information) for further reference.
Btw, nice image :)

Comment: thanks. yes I restarted it on Thursday (not sure exactly what time).

Comment: Check [this](http://elinux.org/Kernel_Debugging_Tips#Adding_timing_information) for further reference...